# Wrong data in session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

There are some wrong numbers in my array

```
<script>
var id=0;
function getId(id2){
 id=id2;
 document.getElementById("idHid").value=id;
document.getElementById("form").submit();
 }
</script>
<?php
$n = 10;
$st = 0;
$_SESSION['cel']= 51;
$razlika = 0;
$idGet=0;
$idArray=array();
$vel = 0;
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
echo "<tr>";
  for($x=0;$x<$n;$x++){
    $st++;
    $id=(($x+1)+($i*$n));

    echo "<td id=".$id." onClick='getId(".$id.")'><b>".$id."</b></td>";
   }
 echo "</tr>"; }
echo "</table>";
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$idGet = $_POST['id'];
$idArray=$_SESSION['ar']; 
$idArray[$vel]=$idGet;
$_SESSION['vel']+=1;
 $_SESSION['ar']=$idArray;
 }else{
 $_SESSION['vel']=0;
 $_SESSION['ar'];
} 
$vel=$_SESSION['vel'];
for($i =0;$i<$vel;$i++){
  echo $idArray[$i]."-".$vel."<br>";
                 }
?>
```

If I click on some td's more than 7 times I start getting errors. I want to save all "id's" in session and I want to save number of clicks.

Comment: Does this work correctly when you do not click a td more than 7 time?

Comment: When you deal with sessions on a page, always add this to the absolut top of the page: `session_start();`

Comment: No, only the last id is correct. Others are wrong. But after 7 times I'm starting to get some errors: Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in --- on line 67
-9

Comment: I have session_start(), just forgot to add it here

Comment: Can you share full code, including what is in you HTML

Comment: this is additional html in the bottom of code :

<form id="form" method="POST">
<input id="idHid" type="hidden" name="id" value="0"/>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure what you want to achieve.
I hope this might help you.

This will store each click and push id to array `$_SESSION['ar']`.

If you want to count the number of click you can count the number of entries in the array. That is equivalent to number of clicks

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    array_push($_SESSION['ar'], $_POST['id']);
}
var_dump($_SESSION['ar']);
var_dump(count($_SESSION['ar']));
```

Make sure length of array keeps on increasing on each click, and id is recored twice